# Connect to Java Server problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have written an ActionScript client program that tries to connect to a local java server that listens on port 8787.
 The code is the following:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.system.Security;

public class Main extends Sprite {

    // Properties

    private var socket:Socket;

    // Constructor

    public function Main() {

        Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://localhost:8787");
        socket = new Socket();          
        socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnectHandler);

        socket.connect("192.168.0.3", 8787);

    }

    // Methods

    private function onConnectHandler(event:Event):void {

        trace("The socket is now connected...");
        var myspr:Sprite = new Sprite();
        myspr.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        myspr.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 60);
        myspr.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(myspr);

    }

}
```

But in the flash cs4 IDE i get the following message:

`Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2031: Socket Error.
    at Main()`

While when i drop the swf in firefox i get:

`SecurityError: Error #2010: Local-with-filesystem SWF files are not permitted to use sockets.
    at flash.net::Socket/internalConnect()
    at flash.net::Socket/connect()
    at Main()`

Note: instead of "192.168.0.3", i have also test 127.0.0.1 and localhost without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing locally, you need to add your swf to Flash's Global Security Settings permissions:

[Flash Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502)

Add the location of your local swf to the trust file list and set it to "always allow."